# English idioms usage: "shack up", "give leg bail"

Tags: idioms, phrase-usage

Are the idioms "shack up" (=sleep with) and "give leg bail" (=flee) in use now?

Are they widely used? Are they easily recognized?

Comment: 'Shack up' is not used as much as formerly, but is still almost universally understood. 'Give leg bail' is an expression that I've never heard in my fifty-plus years.

Comment: What @JeffZeitlin said (apart from it being sixty-plus years).

Comment: I’ve also never heard *give leg bail* but I see it referenced at https://www.etymonline.com/word/bail

Comment: @JamesRandom I can endorse that with my seventy-plus years. (A "leg-bail" is potentially an item used in the game of cricket, but I don't think we are talking about one of those.)

Answer (score 2):

In British usage, to 'shack up with' someone means to start living together with that person, in the same house or dwelling place (a shack is a wooden hut or cabin). It is still quite common. To 'give leg bail' (to run away from police or justicial custody) is late 18th century criminal slang and not at all common, in fact I have only seen it in old books. There is a modern equivalent used by UK police - to 'have it away on one's toes'.

Comment: Not just BrE for 'shack up'; it's almost universally recognized in AmE as well, though perhaps used less - certainly less than it used to be.